# Displaying settings internally represented with sections in Android Listview

Tags: android, ios, android-listview, cross-platform, baseadapter

I'm writing an application for iOS and Android in parallell and I am facing a small problem.

I am displaying a list of settings to the user and the settings data is internally represented in settings for section, like this:

```
Section
    Section object
    Section object
Section
    Section object
```

etc.

In iOS, when the user clicks a setting object, or when the system wants to paint the view for it, it calls a method with an `NSIndexPath` object. For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and the sections are handled automatically.

In Android, the listviews are "flattened", lacking better terminology. So that a method is called only with a row index:

```
public Object getItem(int position);
```

Now it is actually a quite hard problem to solve trying to represet sections directly in the Adapter (`MySettingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter`).

Right now this problem is solved by flattening the entire underlaying data structure, but it's a lot of duplicated code for almost nothing. The nicer solution I can think of is to do something like the following in my `MySettingsAdapter`:

```
class MySettingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    MyInternalDataStructure settingsData;
    int sections;
    int rowsForSection[sections];

    public MySettingsAdapter (MyInternalDataStructure settingsData) {
        this.settingsData = settingsData;
        this.sections = settingsData.sections;
        for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++) {
            rowsForSection[i] = settingsData.settingsInSection[i].size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        int sectionFromPostion;
        int rowFromPosition;
        // Calculate section and row here... 
        return settingsData.getSetting(sectionFromPostion, rowFromPosition);
    } 
}
```

And I just can't get the calculations for `sectionFromPostion` and `rowFromPostion` right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Android does not have quite the same ability in regards to sections as you can achieve with the `UITableView`.  However Android does provide a solution, the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).  While similar to a `ListView` it works a bit differently and interacts with a different type of adapter.

Android provides the [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) that you can use with the `ExpandableListView`. I'll warn you now. It's clunky and pretty restricting.  Additionally, it requires you to organize your data into a `List` of `Maps` which in itself can be a pain to do.

Alternatively, you can create your own adapter for the `ExpandableListView` by implementing the [BaseExpandableListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html).  It's very similar to implementing the `BaseAdapter`.  It just has a few extra bells and whistles to support a tier like structure.

Basically all these `Expandable...[foo]` classes introduce the idea of having a group *(the section)* and children *(the data under a section)*. Instead of having an `index` to the data in your adapter, you'll have a `groupPosition` and a `childPosition`.  Meanwhile the `ExpandableListView` has this sorta murky middle notion of positions as it works with group/child positions, packed positions, and flattened positions.

As a side note. Depending on how your data is organized, I'd suggest checking out the Rolodex Adapters found in this [3rd party library](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters). They are meant to make working with `ExpandableListViews` easier and has plenty of code examples and a demo app to help get you going.